# Problem to execute https connection from a servlet: http 404 error occours

Tags: servlets, https, http-status-code-404

From my Tomcat's servlet I execute an https connection to an external servlet.
This is the code:

```
    HttpsURLConnection hpcon = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(surl);
        hpcon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        hpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        hpcon.setDoInput(true);
        hpcon.setDoOutput(true);
        hpcon.setUseCaches(false);
        hpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(hpcon.getOutputStream());
        String params = "user=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8");
        params += "&psswd=" + URLEncoder.encode(pssw, "UTF-8");
        params += "&metodo=" + URLEncoder.encode(metodo, "UTF-8");
        wr.write(params);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        hpcon.connect();
        int respCode = hpcon.getResponseCode();
        if (respCode == 200) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hpcon.getInputStream()));
            String response = "";
            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += output;
            }
            if (response.indexOf("-") > 0) {
                response = "-12";
                System.out.println("ret = -12 - response = " + response);
            }
            br.close();
        } else {
            ret = "-11";
            System.out.println("ret = -11 - respCode = " + respCode);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ret = "-10";
        System.out.println("ret = -10");
    } finally {
        if (hpcon != null) {
            hpcon.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Where surl is the full url of a servlet present in a different domain and the three parameters are read from a db table (the third really is fixed and is the operation that is make by the external servlet).
The result is:
ret = -11 - respCode = 404

Before make the connection I turn off the certificate's verify using the above code:

```
try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I execute the same servlet manually from a browser with parameters in get mode all run correctly.

I tried to execute it on my code using the get mode and passing the three parameters in query string, but the result is the same.

How can I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: 404 simply means that the url does not exist / is unreachable from the perspective of this Java program. This is not a servlet related problem if it works fine in a plain vanilla web browser.

Comment: Is it possible that this depends on the SSL certificate?
Or that in the configuration of Tomcat on Apache HTTP Server there is something to fix regarding the visibility in https compared to http?

Comment: No. It would have thrown a SSL exception if the URL were reachable while the cert is invalid.

Comment: How can I do to set the external servlet visible to another?
I must to configure the Tomcat instance of external domain in any way?

Comment: I'd say there's a typo in the URL being used.

Comment: No, because I've tested the same url (copy & paste) in get mode on browser and it run correctly.

Comment: So if you replace POST by GET in URLConnection code merely for sake of testing then it doesn't anymore return 404?

Comment: I've tried it, but with the same result.
With my provider I have discovered that that call was blocked by mod security. We have disable it.